# How can I find the Transfer Function in Z-domain?

Tags: transfer-function, signal-processing, signal

This is my signal;

$y[n]=x[n]+0.8x[n-0.2]$

When I take Z-transform I get;

$Y[z]=X[z]+0.8z^\frac{-1}{5}X[z])$

Then I found the Transfer function as;

$H[z]=\frac{Y[z]}{X[z]}$

$H[z]=1+0.8z^\frac{-1}{5}$

I want to extract the numerator and the denominator parts of this $H[z]$, but all the examples I see have integer z exponentials as -1,-2 etc. How can I save the function from 0.2 exponential?

Comment: Where did the first equation come from?

Comment: From my DSP term project. But this complexity is on me. I made a mistake by taking time delay 200ms(0.2s) directly without changing it to sample size. My signal has 44.1kHz sampling frequency and it gives 8820.  Thus the initial signal comes as $y[n]=x[n]+0.8x[n-8820]$. Thanks for helping me realize my mistake.